# How can I add an event listener to scrolling content?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I want to put some mouse event to scrolling text in dynamic text field.

For example: I type several sentences into one dynamic text field. For each sentence, I want to have a different mouse event. Like this:

```
sentenceA.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, functionA);

function functionA(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
trace("bla");
}
```

How can I add an eventlistener to each sentence in the scrolling text? Because the position of the mouse event should move when the relative text scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

here you go...

```
_txt.htmlText = "<a href='event:sentence1'>This is one sentenc.</a> <a href='event:sentence2'>This is another sentence.</a>"
_txt.addEventListener(TextEvent.LINK, clickCopyHandler);

function clickCopyHandler(e:TextEvent):void {
    trace(e.text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     var sentences:Array = [ sentenceA, sentenceB, ...... ];

     function clickAllText(e:MouseEvent):void 
     {
        var index:int;
        for each(var s:String in sentences) 
        {
            index = dynamicTextField.text.indexOf(s);
            if(index >= 0 && index <= 3) 
            {
              //if the sentence is in the front 
              this["sentence"+sentences.indexOf(s)]();
              break;                                                                                                                        
            }
        }
     }

     function sentence0():void 
     {
     }

     function sentence1():void 
     {
     }
```

If that is not the case, you would need to either use different text fields, or
         get the proximity of the mouse point to the sentence x and y location on the 
         display.

Answer (score 0):

Take a closer look at [flash.event.TextEvent.LINK](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#event%3alink), it's thrown when you click on html text which has an attribute href='event:someText'. Consider the following example

```
var tf:TextField = new TextField();
tf.htmlText = "<a href='event:first'>sentence1.</a><a href='event:second'>sentence2.</a>";
tf.addEventListener("link", clickHandler); //link is value of flash.event.TextEvent.LINK

function clickHandler(e:TextEvent):void {
    //here should be something like the following
    if (e.text == "first") sentence1();
    else if (e.text == "second") sentence2();
}
```

well, I guess you caught the idea! The problem is that sentences are to be put into  tag, but you can make links look like ordinary text. If that variant does not fits your needs, you may try to compare selection boundaries(`tf.selectionBeginIndex` and `tf.selectionEndIndex`) with boundaries of sentences after click.